# How to run 0bda:a811 Realtek USB WiFi adaptor on Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: usb, ubuntu-14.04, wifi-configuration, 802.11ac

As my onboard WiFi Chipset (Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b]) does not support the 11AC-standard, according to my research, I bought an USB-Adapter.

Following the advice given on

https://askubuntu.com/questions/923222/how-can-i-enable-a-realtek-usb-antenna

and

https://askubuntu.com/questions/787017/where-do-usb-wifi-drivers-go-16-04

I installed installed the driver provided on

https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi

by adding the repository and calling

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8192du-dkms
```

However,

```
modprobe -c | grep -i "0bda.*ab11"
```

returns nothing and

```
usb-devices | awk '/a811/' RS=
```

ends with

```
...
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 6 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
```

Can you please give me any hints what to do next to circle the problem?

Comment: It is `rtl8812au`. Search for solutions.